# Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function

Tags: reactjs, redux

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import Map from './components/map/container/map';
import App from './App';
import './index.css';
import shell from './shared/utility/shell';
import { render } from 'react-dom'
import { Provider } from 'react-redux'
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux'
import { routerMiddleware, ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux'
import thunk from 'redux-thunk'
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory'
import rootReducer from './reducers'
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';
import { Routes } from './config';

const history = createHistory();
const target = document.querySelector('#root')
const initialState = {};
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [
thunk,
routerMiddleware(history)
 ];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension;

if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
enhancers.push(devToolsExtension());
 }
}
const composedEnhancers = compose(
applyMiddleware(...middleware),
  ...enhancers
);
const store = createStore(
 rootReducer,
 initialState,
 composedEnhancers
);
render(
  <Provider store={store}>
   <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
    <div>
     <Routes />
    </div>
   </ConnectedRouter>
  </Provider>,
  target
   )
 registerServiceWorker();
 ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
 registerServiceWorker();
```

---

I am trying to call an API from with the help of redux and display its data in a table. I am getting this error. Above is my `index.js` file.

---

> 1.
>   Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

---

> 2.
>   React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in.

I have referred to many answers I am not able to recognize the error.

Comment: You are attempting to render something which is not a react component or function. Most likely the problem is your `App` or `Routes` since those seem to be the custom ones you are rendering. Double check the exports from those files, and any files they import.

Comment: like @AustinGreco said, it's an import/export issue. [check this](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4477)

Comment: I don't know you solved it or not, I was running into the same trouble once, and found out I applied the codes for react-router-redux@next(5.0.0-alphaN)  on the older version of react-router-redux.

Answer (score 81):

Problem is in the import statements. You have not used curly braces while importing some components like `createHistory`.

If a component uses a default export like:

```
export default X
```

Then you can simply import it like:

```
import X from './X';
```

But if you are using a named export like:

```
export const X=1;
```

Then you need to import it in curly braces like:

```
import {X} from './X';
```

So have a look at your imports. This will resolve your issue.

Comment: If in another folder i have mentioned like this...import _map from './container/map';
export { _map as Map }; Do I need to enclose Map in curly braces?

Comment: you can directly write export when declaring class as: export default class Map{  render{    return();}} and import it like import Map from ./class

Comment: After correcting createHistory I am getting this error._WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_10_history_createBrowserHistory__.createHistory is not a function

Comment: Is it because of this ?

Comment: do history package contains createBrowserHisto‌​ry function?Please check it.

Comment: refer to this https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/issues/4006

Comment: No, putting createHistory in curly braces doesnt work it gives me error at Connectedrouter

Comment: It wasted my  20-30 minutes and I couldn't figure out where I was doing wrong. Now I know what it was, thanks for the answer :)

Answer (score 15):

I ran into the same problem in my react application. It's definitely your import statements as stated above.
I changed:

`import {x} from '/x.js'`  to  `import x from '/x.js'`

and that got the job done

Answer (score 7):

I've also run into this error when one of the nested components attempted to render a component that did not exist. Specifically, I attempted to use

```
<Button ... />
```

a react-native component in React, where I should have been using

```
<button ... />
```

Answer (score 4):

Check you aren't importing your component name in braces like this:

```
import {SomeComponent} from '../path/to/SomeComponent'; // nope
```

I realised I had done that and so I changed it to this and it started working:

```
import SomeComponent from '../path/to/SomeComponent'; // yes
```

The `{}` is for selecting from imports with multiple exports like the React components etc, and without you get what the `export default` is.

Comment: perfect i was exported the component import {SomeComponent} from '../path/to/SomeComponent'; earlier. now its seems fine. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It can also be caused from where the entry point is.

In my case, the App.js was calling index.js (where the developer console was identifying the error, and where my RenderDom call was).

However, App.js was referencing a component, and it was within that component that I had the error (a reference to yet another component that did not exist).

Answer (score 2):

For me, I faced this issue when I forget to use react-redux's `connect` in my export.

So,

changing:

```
 export default(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContentTile);
```

To:

```
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ContentTile);
```

solved the issue. Really silly mistake

Answer (score 2):

There are several reasons why this error might occur.

It is definitely related directly to an issue with one of your imports. This could be:

1. A missing/miss-imported module from a npm package.
2. A component missing the `export` or an altogether empty component
   attempting to be imported.
3. mixed up named/default export/import

Answer (score 1):

In my case I solved it changing the components: They were written in functions declarations and I change them by classical Class declarations (`class App extends React.Component` instead of `function App()` )

Comment: Hey! But why would that matter? It should work both with class and functional components. Did you find the reason?

Answer (score 1):

You may also get this error if a sub-component of the component that the error references has not exported its function/class:

So the problem isn't in the referenced component but in a component that it is importing (which is not referenced in the error text).

Took me a while to find this bugger.

Answer (score 1):

To add to previous replies, you also get this error if one of the components *within* the component you are trying to import is empty / does not have a correct render method.

Answer (score 1):

Old but relevant to the discussion. Upgraded code base to React 18 from React 16 and the dealt the same error. Here is the code in question.

```
import { Form, InputGroup } from 'react-bootstrap';
export default function Login() {

return (
    <Form >
        <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Name</Form.Label>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group>
            <Form.Label>Email</Form.Label>
        </Form.Group>
        <Form.Group style={{ marginBottom: 30 }}>
            <Form.Label>Password</Form.Label>
            <InputGroup>
                <InputGroup.Append>
                    <InputGroup.Text onClick={() => setShowPassword(!showPassword)}>
                    </InputGroup.Text>
                </InputGroup.Append>
            </InputGroup>
        </Form.Group>
    </Form>
);}
```

Now here is the code that was causing the error. Removed this code and all was good. Almost impossible to track down.

```
 <InputGroup.Append></InputGroup.Append>
```

Wasted about 5 hours on this...

Answer (score 0):

As was sayed above, this issue with import. In my case it's was a CSSTransitionGroup import. After npm update the package 'react-transition-group' no longer contains CSSTransitionGroup, but it's contains different exports, like CSSTransition and TransitionGroup. So i just replace line:

```
import CSSTransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/CSSTransitionGroup';
```

with

```
import TransitionGroup from 'react-transition-group/TransitionGroup';
```

Answer (score 0):

I also had the similar problem while attempting to add routes into my application.
I then realised that i was importing { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router"; instead of correctly importing it from  react-router-dom as below
 import { BrowserRouter, Route } from "react-router-dom". 
Thanks to the online community

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you export the component. And if you are already exporting, then you might have missed the default.

```
export default function App(){
 ...
}
```

Comment: i use `export default` still facing the same issue

Answer (score 0):

It's a special case, but Recharts threw this error for me when I attempted to put two charts inside one ResponsiveContainer. That is [not supported](https://github.com/recharts/recharts/issues/1130).

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, It could be as a result of importing from the wrong library, like in my experience, where I should have imported Input component from react native elements.

```
import { View, ActivityIndicator, Input } from 'react-native';
import { Input, Button } from 'react-native-elements';
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case I resolved the problem by removing undefined component.
I imported that component from wrong module.

Answer (score 0):

My problem is solved, the problem was instead of using

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-router-dom'
```

I used

```
import { NavLink } from 'react-dom'
```

I want to say this, coding includes paying attention to details.

Answer (score 0):

I got this error just because import "Flat**L**ist" as "Flat**l**ist" in react native expo project. And I spend one and a half hour to realize that :(

Comment: Disadvantages of not using ESLint or TypeScript 

Answer (score 0):

Well, I got this stupid error, which took me hours to figure out, because I upgraded bootstrap from v4 to v5 and Popover.Title is changed to Popover.Header. I wish the error message could be a little bit more specific.

Answer (score 0):

I experienced the  same thing and realized `createNativeStackNavigator()` was missing its parenthesis.

It formerly looked like `const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator;` instead of `const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();`.

Answer (score 0):

I have used the arrow function to crate components. then I changed it to a normal function. then it got solved

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -1):

for me i was trying to route in app.js some component that have problem, so index.js  will not render the  / because of that in-proper import in app.js

so alwasy make sure components in app.js are working properly