# How to properly import components in React JS: expected a string but got: object ERROR

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to develop a react app using Create React App. So far, seems quite straightforward until I hit a brick wall with the error: `Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.`

Frustratingly, I've seen similar questions on SO and attempted to follow the solutions. 
This SO post: [Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897070/element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-a-class) suggests what I think the solution to the problem might be however, I am not getting any joy. I tried removing the curly braces but it made no difference.

Here's my code or at least where I think the issue might be:

Firstly, the `<!-- .src/store.js -->` file:

```
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } from 'redux';
import { routerMiddleware } from 'react-router-redux';
import thunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createHistory from 'history/createBrowserHistory';
import rootReducer from './modules';

export const history = createHistory();

// history.pushLater = (...args) => setImmediate(() => history.push(...args));

const initialState = {};
const enhancers = [];
const middleware = [
    thunk,
    routerMiddleware(history)
];

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'development') {
    const devToolsExtension = window.devToolsExtension;

    if (typeof devToolsExtension === 'function') {
        enhancers.push(devToolsExtension())
    }
}

const composedEnhancers = compose(
    applyMiddleware(...middleware),
    ...enhancers
);

const store = createStore(
    rootReducer,
    initialState,
    composedEnhancers
);

export default store;
```

and secondly, the `<!-- ./src/index.js -->` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import { ConnectedRouter } from 'react-router-redux';
import store, { history } from './store';
import App from './containers/app';
import './index.css';
// import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

const target = document.querySelector('#root');

render (
    <Provider store={store}>
        <ConnectedRouter history={history}>
            <div>
                <App />
            </div>
        </ConnectedRouter>
    </Provider>,
    target
);

// registerServiceWorker();
```

In the file .src/store.js, `createHistory` is imported but I'm not certain if this is correct.

`history` is exported like so:

`export const history = createHistory();`

so I imagine it should be imported with curly braces like so:

`import store, { history } from './store';`

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Please all forgive me. I just noticed something else in a completely different file. I realised that the way the export is being done is correct and the way I am importing is also correct, however, the error remained which caused lots of headaches. To my shame, the issue was with a completely different file. It was actually a school-boy error:

I was doing:

`export default App();`

instead of:

`export default App;`

{face palms}

This is the complete file with corrections:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Route, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Home from '../home';
import About from '../about';

const App = () => (
    <div>
        <header>
            <Link to="/">Home</Link>
            <Link to="/about-us">About</Link>
        </header>

        <main>
            <Route exact path="/" component={Home} />
            <Route exact path="/about-us" component={About} />
        </main>
    </div>
);

export default App;
```

Again, apologies! It might help someone.