# Minified React error #130 after Deploy to Vercel

Tags: reactjs, api, deployment, vercel

on local everything working fine but after deploy /map not working.

full repo: https://github.com/selcukguler0/weather_app

live: https://weather-app-git-master-selcukguler0.vercel.app

stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/github/selcukguler0/weather_app?file=src/Map.jsx

only map not working.

map.jsx

```
import TurkeyMap from "turkey-map-react";
import { GridLoader } from "react-spinners"; //Loading animation
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import { Tooltip } from "antd";
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";

export default function Map() {
    console.log("Type of TurkeyMAp",typeof TurkeyMap);
    console.log("object" === typeof TurkeyMap);
    const navigate = useNavigate();

    return (
        <div className="">
            <header className="flex justify-center items-center gap-3 gap-x-4 ">
                <Link
                    className="text-[40px] text-center font-bold text-blue-500 hover:text-red-500"
                    to={"/"}>
                    Home
                </Link>
                <h1
                    className="text-[40px] text-center font-bold  text-white hover:text-red-500"
                    to={"/map"}>
                    Map
                </h1>
                <Link
                    className="text-[40px] text-center font-bold text-blue-500 hover:text-red-500"
                    to={"/cities"}>
                    Cities
                </Link>
            </header>
            <div>
                <TurkeyMap
                    onClick={({ name }) => {
                        navigate(`/city/${name}`);
                    }}
                    cityWrapper={(cityComponent, cityData) => (
                        <Tooltip
                            title={`${cityData.plateNumber} - ${cityData.name}`}
                            key={cityData.id}>
                            {cityComponent}
                        </Tooltip>
                    )}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Navigating to `/map` and opening the console reveals the 130 error which redirects you to [this link](https://reactjs.org/docs/error-decoder.html/?args%5B%5D=object&args%5B%5D=&invariant=130) and shows you the following error:

> Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: object.

According to this thread, the problem is in your imports: [Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44897070/element-type-is-invalid-expected-a-string-for-built-in-components-or-a-class)

Comment: tried to import with `import {TurkeyMap} from "turkey-map-react";` this time library not working

Comment: I cloned your repo and ran it on my machine. The issue is `TurkeyMap`. The developer of `TurkeyMap` has marked that `TurkeyMap` is incompatible with React 18 which you are using. Usually, using an older library doesn't result in any conflicts, but unfortunately that seems to be the case here. Maybe you could kindly ask the developer to make it compatible? Otherwise you would have to come up with your own solution or try to copy and paste the `TurkeyMap` source code until it works.